# Script to show some important information

Tags: linux, centos

I'm new to here.

Is it possible to show important details such as root password and mysql on 
var/www/html/index.php
or anyone can write that? thanks.
(I am using a VPS- centos 6)

Comment: What do you mean with _anyone can write that_? You want retrive this information with php?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  We will not write code for you.  We will help you figure out why your own code is not working if you can show us the relevant code and clearly explain the problem you are having.  If you are looking for pre-written code, consider a search engine.

Comment: Sorry about that, so here is my question is it possible to execute a command inside the vps using only browser with my php?

Comment: `code
<?php
$output = shell_exec('sh /root/.chaoshost/Start2hours');
echo "$output";
?>
`
    but it does not work in me.. here is my Start2hours script: http://pastebin.com/N2aJixew